# Problema con java.util.NoSuchElementException en la linea 15

Tags: java, bucles

Estoy creando un programa para clase que cumpla ciertas cosas y las cumplo. El problema esta en la linea 17 segun el programa que nos corrige. He estado buscando y parece ser que es algun problema con las entradas del escaner, pero apenas llevo un mes y no se donde buscar o como solucionar esto.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class divisores {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder acumulador = new StringBuilder(); //Se usa para acumular en text

        boolean a = true;


while (a) {
    int n=1;

    String[] nrm = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    int numero_entrada = sc.nextInt(); //java.util.NoSuchElementException
    String numeros_divible = ""; //limpio la cadena
    acumulador = new StringBuilder(); //Se crea una nueva cadena ya que si no se guarda lo anterior
if (numero_entrada < 0){
    a = false;
}

    while (n <= numero_entrada){
        if (numero_entrada % n == 0) {
            acumulador.append(n).append(" ");
        }
        n++;    }

    numeros_divible = String.valueOf(acumulador);

    System.out.println(numeros_divible);

}
sc.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: de que te sirve tener el array nrm???